# FirstOrDefault returning Unexpected Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When I set a default value if the set is empty and call `.FirstOrDefault()` with a condition that isn't met I'm not getting my default value, but the type's default value:

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Console.WriteLine(list.DefaultIfEmpty(1).FirstOrDefault(i => i == 4)); // Outputs 4, as expected
Console.WriteLine(list.DefaultIfEmpty(1).FirstOrDefault(i => i > 5));  // Outputs 0, why??
```

This seems unintuitive since I'm setting `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to 1. Why doesn't this output a 1?

Comment: the default value for integer (since it wasn't found) is a 0.

Comment: Why doesn't it take the value I set using `.DefaultIfEmpty` since no values are in the set returned that match the condition?

Comment: Because `DefaultIfEmpty` applies to the `list` not the result.

Comment: You call DefaultIfEmpty on a list that isn't empty, so you'll never get that to happen.

Comment: Six answers saying the same thing!  Can we get 7?

Comment: You are not "setting" anything. DefaultifEmpty does not create some persistent setting. It is a one-time operation. It think this is your misunderstanding.

Comment: My question was why it didn't use the default value since my resulting set from the condition was empty. Guess that wasn't clear. Ok, makes sense but still seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: It DID use the default. It's not using the default you're giving it, because that's not what DefaultIfEmpty does. Guessing you're reading it as if it is a Fluent kind of function. It's not really.

Comment: @NickGotch what DefultIfEmpty does is if you have a array of size 0 it swaps it out with an array of size 1 with the value you passed in, thats it, it does not change the default value of `int` for the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You appear to misunderstand how [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) works.

`list.DefaultIfEmpty(1)` returns a singleton sequence containing `1` if the source collection (`list`) is empty. Since `list` is not empty, this has no effect and the source sequence is returned.

As a result, your query is effectively the same as:

```
int result = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i > 5);
```

The default of `int` is `0` so `FirstOrDefault` returns `0` if the condition is not met, which it is not since `list` contains no elements greater than 5.

You can get the behaviour you want using:

```
int result = list.Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault(i => i > 5) ?? 1;
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Console.WriteLine(list.Where(i => i > 5).DefaultIfEmpty(1).First());
```

By placing the `Where` before the `DefaultIfEmpty`, an empty collection will return an enumerable with one item. You can then use `First` to get that element.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is the behavior I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for integer is `0`.

`FirstOrDefault` return the first occurrency or default value, in your case, you a re using `int`, so, it is `0`.  If you want a exception when do not have a item, try using `First(x => x > 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault` refers to the value of the expression `default(T)` where `T` is the type of the collection, not the first value of your list. You cannot change that behaviour and you also cannot change the default value for a type.

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault() This returns an int, int is not nullable therefore default is 0.  Check out the default values table on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The default value for non-nullable int is 0.  Since nothing in your list is > 5, it returns the default value.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultIfEmpty does not set the default value. It gives you a list with exactly this one value as a default, if the original list is empty.